# integers when reading a csv file in python

Tags: python, csv, floating-point

I'm trying to read a csv file in python, so that I can then find the average of the values in one of the columns using numpy.average.
My script looks like this:

```
import os
import numpy
import csv

listing = os.listdir('/path/to/directory/of/files/i/need')
os.chdir('/path/to/directory/of/files/i/need')


for file in listing[1:]:    
    r = csv.reader(open(file, 'rU'))   
    for row in r:
        if len(row)<2:continue
        if float(row[2]) <=0.05:
            avg = numpy.average(float(row[2]))
    print avg
```

but I keep on getting the error ValueError: invalid literal for float(). The csv reader seems to be reading the numbers as string, and won't allow me to convert it to a float. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you provide a sample from the csv file that includes one of the values the script chokes on?

Comment: I guess that you have passed an empty string to it so you need to add a simple check for this - 'if row[2].strip() and float(row[2]) <=0.05:'

Comment: @Artisom: This would result in the error message "empty string for float()" instead of "invalid literal for float()".

Comment: @Sven but i have tried this and it throws 'ValueError: invalid literal for float(): ' - but i am using IronPython 2.6. Have checked in python 2.6 and got 'empty string for float()'

Comment: just remembered that the first line of every file is string. however, when i try to skip the first line by doing for row in r[1:]: instead of for row in r: i get TypeError: '_csv.reader' object is unsubscriptable

Comment: It is bcoz it is an iterator object not a list

Comment: thank you @waffle paradox and others for helping me fix my script!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by the comments, your program is running into problems with the headers.

Two solutions of this are to use `r.next()`, which skips a line, before your `for` loop, or to use the `DictReader` class.  The advantage of the `DictReader` class is that you can treat each row as a dictionary instead of a tuple, which may make for more readability in some cases, but you do have to pass the list of headers to it in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
float(row[2])
```

to:

```
float(row[2].strip("'\""))
```